# ¿Cómo puedo escribir una expresión regular para encontrar números con comas cada tres dígitos?

Tags: regex

Por ejemplo debe coincidir:

- '42'
- '1,234'
- '6,368,745'

Y no con:

- '1234' (no tiene comas)
- '12,34,567' (tiene solo 2 dígitos entre comas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que la siguiente expresión funcionará correctamente en todos los casos:

```
^\d{1,3}(:?,\d{3})*$
```

Al menos [en esta demo](https://regex101.com/r/zphzD9/1/tests) supera todos los test que has propuesto.

La expresión se lee así:

- Tras el inicio de la cadena (`^`) ha de venir un grupo de entre 1 y 3 dígitos (`\d{1,3}`).
- Después, opcionalmente un grupo de no captura `(?:...)` compuesto de una coma y otros tres dígitos
- Este último grupo puede repetirse cualquier número de veces (`*`).
- Y tras él, el final de la cadena (`$`)

Comment: Estuve probando y no funciono para 4 o más dígitos:

Comment: En casos con 4 dígitos o más no funciona: 
numRegex = re.compile(r'\d{1,3}(:?,\d{3})*$')

Comment: @JoséIgnacio No te entiendo... un caso con 4 dígitos es por ejemplo `1234`. Dices que "no funciona" ¿a qué te refieres? Según tu especificación ese caso no debería producir matches, y según los tests de la página que te enlacé en la respuesta puedes ver que no genera matches (en esos test, el test "pasa" con éxito porque no genera matches, que es la condición que puse en el test). ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo concreto que "no funcione", qué salida esperas para ese caso y el código python que ejecutas?

Comment: Este es el código Python que ejecuto con tu expresión regular y si produce match: >>> import re
           >>> numRegex = re.compile(r'\d{1,3}(:?,\d{3})*$')
           >>> num1 = numRegex.search('1234')
           >>> num1.group()
                                '234'

Comment: @JoséIgnacio Ah, claro, entiendo. Pero es que la expresión regular que escribí era para usarla con `re.match()` y en ese caso verás que no encaja. La diferencia entre `match()` y `search()` es que el primero exige que la expresión regular encaje con la cadena completa, mientras que a `search()` le vale encajar en _cualquier parte_ de la cadena dada. Si necesitas usar `search()` puedes poner como expresión regular `r'^\d{1,3}(:?,\d{3})*$`. El `^` inicial representa el inicio de la cadena. Así sólo encaja al principio y evita que encaje una "subcadena" cualquiera.

Comment: Es la misma expresión regular que escribiste para match()

Comment: Es verdad, es la que había puesto en mi respuesta, pero no es la que tú usaste en el código que pegaste en el comentario anterior. En la tuya faltaba el `^` inicial. Con él, ni `match()` ni `search()` producen resultado (retornan `None`)

Comment: Ahora si se ejecuta correctamente en el python shell pero cree una función y no devuelve nada. Porque?

Comment: No sé qué has hecho en tu función, no puedo saber qué retorna, o por qué no retorna nada. ¿Le has puesto un `return algo`?